# How can I produce an xml sequence diagram?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, ndepend

I'd like to have something similar to the following screen from [Callgraph viewer for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/callgraph-viewer)

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

With NDepend you can get some **call graphs**. The call graph can be done at several level: assemblies, namespaces, classes or methods. In the GIF below see a classes call graph and how it is generated. [See the related documentation here](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Call).

[image: NDepend call graph generation]